# OBIEE12c configuration failed with oracle database 19c

Tags: oracle, obiee

My OBIEE12c configuration failed after proceed 12%.
OBIEE version: 12.2.1.4
Oracle Database version: 19c

Stack Trace:

```
Variable in stdconfigactionhandler  : BI Configuration
progress in calculate progress6
progress in calculate progress6
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Action:BI_Configuration failed with error:Configure BI Failed with Execution of [/u01/app/middleware/bi_home/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh, /u01/app/middleware/bi_home/bi/modules/oracle.bi.configassistant/essbase.py, /u01/app/middleware/bi_home, /u01/app/middleware/bi_home/user_projects/domains/bi12c, weblogic, Expanded, EDWIPRDAPP1, 9502, 9503, ORACLE, oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver, jdbc:oracle:thin:@//EDWIPRDDB-scan:1521/edwprddb, DEVBI, jdbc:oracle:thin:@//EDWIPRDDB-scan:1521/edwprddb, ] failed with exit value 1
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.client.ConfigAction.fail(ConfigAction.java:281)
    at oracle.bi.install.config.actions.BIConfigAction.doExecute(BIConfigAction.java:137)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.client.ConfigAction.execute(ConfigAction.java:405)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.TaskPerformer.run(TaskPerformer.java:88)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.TaskPerformer.startConfigAction(TaskPerformer.java:108)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.ActionRequest.perform(ActionRequest.java:15)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.RequestQueue.performSequentialExecution(RequestQueue.java:284)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.RequestQueue.perform(RequestQueue.java:260)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.standard.StandardConfigActionManager.start(StandardConfigActionManager.java:185)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.boot.ConfigurationExtension.kickstart(ConfigurationExtension.java:82)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.ConfigurationModule.run(ConfigurationModule.java:87)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:820)
In Config Module Finish Event...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following workaround can fix the issue

Step 1: First following command in the current session

export JAVA_OPTIONS="-Doracle.jdbc.fanEnabled=false ${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${JAVA_PROPERTIES}"

export JAVA_OPTIONS

export CONFIG_JVM_ARGS=-Doracle.jdbc.fanEnabled=false

Step 2: Remove or rename the following file

```
    $Oracle_home/oracle_common/lib/ons.jar
```

Ste3. Re-run the configuration assistant

```
  $Oracle_Home/bi/bin/config.sh or config.cmd
```